# SQL JSON_VALUE select parent values

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have this JSON and I need to extract 2 strings

1. Childs of `"properties"` in a column separated by commas.
2. Childs of `"title"` in a column separated by commas.

The results should be

1. ```
   BoxTp, boxNo
   ```
2. ```
   Box Type, Box Number
   ```

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "properties": {
        "BoxTp": {
            "title": "Box Type",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ],
            "description": "Type"
        },
        "boxNo": {
            "title": "Box Number",
            "type": [
                "integer",
                "null"
            ],
            "description": "Box No.",
            "format": "int32"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share sample codes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to parse the input JSON and concatenate the results. Of course, you need SQL Server 2016+ to use the built-in JSON support and SQL Server 2017+ for string aggregation with `STRING_AGG()`:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "properties": {
        "BoxTp": {
            "title": "Box Type",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ],
            "description": "Type"
        },
        "boxNo": {
            "title": "Box Number",
            "type": [
                "integer",
                "null"
            ],
            "description": "Box No.",
            "format": "int32"
        }
    }
}'

SELECT STRING_AGG([key], ', ') AS ChildsOfProperties
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.properties')

SELECT STRING_AGG(j2.title, ', ') AS ChildsOfTitles
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.properties') j1
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (title nvarchar(100) '$.title') j2
```

Result:

```
ChildsOfProperties
-----------------
BoxTp, boxNo

ChildsOfTitles
--------------------
Box Type, Box Number
```

If you need a single statement:

```
SELECT 
   STRING_AGG(j1.[key], ', ') AS ChildSOfProperties,
   STRING_AGG(j2.title, ', ') AS ChildSOfTitles
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.properties') j1
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (title nvarchar(100) '$.title') j2
```